# Rails - undefined method `cattr_accessor' for Log4r:Module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to connect the Log4r with the silence logger from active support with

> Log4r.send :include,
>   ActiveRecord::SessionStore::Extension::LoggerSilencer

But now I get this error if I try to start the server :

I tried it with

```
require 'active_support/all'
```

in my `session_store.rb` and `log4r.rb`, but always get the same error. Anyone with an idea how to fix this ?

```
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-session_store-1.0.0/lib/active_record/session_store/extension/logger_silencer.rb:16:in `block in <module:LoggerSilencer>': undefined method `cattr_accessor' for Log4r:Module (NoMethodError)
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.13/lib/active_support/concern.rb:114:in `class_eval'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.13/lib/active_support/concern.rb:114:in `append_features'
        from C:/SVN/FOS/branches/FOS_5_0/config/initializers/session_store.rb:4:in `include'
        from C:/SVN/FOS/branches/FOS_5_0/config/initializers/session_store.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `block in load'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:609:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:608:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:608:in `block in <class:Engine>'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:150:in `block in tsort_each'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:183:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:210:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:219:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:209:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:203:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:182:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:148:in `tsort_each'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.13/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in `initialize!'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.13/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
        from C:/SVN/FOS/branches/FOS_5_0/config/environment.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `block in require'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
        from C:/SVN/FOS/branches/FOS_5_0/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
        from C:/SVN/FOS/branches/FOS_5_0/config.ru:in `new'
        from C:/SVN/FOS/branches/FOS_5_0/config.ru:in `<main>'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/server.rb:277:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/server.rb:199:in `app'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.13/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:48:in `app'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/server.rb:314:in `wrapped_app'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.13/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:75:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:76:in `block in <top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `tap'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `<top (required)>'
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
        from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

I update my Log4r because the old version I use was not compatible with the new rails. Now it works.

Answer (score 0):

`cattr_accessor` should be `attr_accessor` in the `logger_silencer.rb` file on line 16. Im pretty sure thats it, let use know if it's not.

Comment: `cattr_accessor` is intentional - it's a method provided by ActiveSupport in Rails that defines class (and instance accessors) for class attributes in a similar way to `attr_accessor` does for instance variables.